# How to give background color for Cf# mode in aem?

Tags: aem

In AEM, I want to give a background color for the header while the page is in CF# mode.

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: Check if `cq.authoring.dialog` clientlib gets loaded in `cf#` mode before following the below steps.

Use `cq.authoring.dialog` clientlib and `jQuery`.

- Create a clientlib with categories as `cq.authoring.dialog`. Scripts in this clientlib are loaded only in the [author instance](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/developing-components.html#CreatingaClientLibraryforStyleandBehavior).
- Add a class to your header dialog using the `granite:class` attribute if you are using `coralui` or `class` if otherwise, this is to hook onto the field in header using script in the above clientlib

> ```
>   <header
>     jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
>     sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
>     fieldLabel="ID"
>     granite:class="headerSelector"
>     name="./header"
>     required="{Boolean}true"/>
> ```

- You'll notice the class name `headerSelector` registered above in the DOM.
- Use one of the OOTB granite event listeners like `foundation-contentloaded` to fire the script on initialization of the dialog.
- Add background colors through `jQuery`

> ```
> $(document).on('foundation-contentloaded', function (e) {//event fires when dialog loads
>     var $headerField= $('.headerSelector');
>     $headerField.css('background-color','blue');
> })
> ```